# How to calculate textboxes value in jQuery and html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a problem in jQuery in html
I have the codes which execute product but I need some changes in calculation, below are my codes
All result will be calculated in one field as I did

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<script>
$(document).on('keyup','input.expenses',function(){
  $expenses = $(this).parents('table').find('.expenses');
  $expenseTotal = $(this).parents('table').find('#expenses_sum');
  $expenseTotal.val('1');
  $.each($expenses,function(index,object){      
    if($(object).val()!='')
    {
 $expenseTotal.val(parseInt($expenseTotal.val())*parseInt($(object).val()));
    }
  })
});
</script>


<table border="1">
  <tr>
      <th>No</th>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>Total</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><input class="expenses"></td>
      <td><input class="expenses"></td>  
      <td><input class="expenses"></td><td>
      <input id="expenses_sum"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td><input class="expenses"></td>
      <td><input class="expenses"></td>
      <td><input class="expenses"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td><input class="expenses"></td>
      <td><input class="expenses"></td>
      <td><input class="expenses"></td>
  </tr>

</table>
 
</body>
</html>
```

The logic I need is

**A TIMES C**

**(B TIMES C)-(A TIMES C)**

Then display the result
I want to manager each textbox itself in jquery in order to make calculation
Please anyone can help me

Comment: Side note; rather than sticking the running result in a DOM Element that you then have to turn around and parse every time you want to modify it mathematically; use a variable, modify the variable, and put the final result in the Element at the end.

Comment: is each row supposed to have its own total?

Comment: No, all rows must display result in one cell as my codes work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only want to work within the row instance where the input you edit exists then use `find()` within that row to gather all the expenses class elements and to set the total

Something like:

```js
$(document).on('keyup','input.expenses',function(){
   var $row = $(this).closest('tr'),
       // collect the 3 inputs in this row only
       $exp = $row.find('.expenses'),
       a = $exp.eq(0).val(),// first is a
       b = $exp.eq(1).val(),// second is b
       c = $exp.eq(2).val();// third is c
       //(B TIMES C)-(A TIMES C)
   var total = b*c - a*c;
   
   $row.find('.expenses_sum').text( total)

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
      <th>No</th>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>Total</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><input class="expenses"></td>
      <td><input class="expenses"></td>  
      <td><input class="expenses"></td>
      <td class="expenses_sum"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td><input class="expenses"></td>
      <td><input class="expenses"></td>
      <td><input class="expenses"></td>
      <td class="expenses_sum"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td><input class="expenses"></td>
      <td><input class="expenses"></td>
      <td><input class="expenses"></td>
      <td class="expenses_sum"></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Note I have not done any validation of the user input and leave that to you

Comment: Hi charlietfl, that codes work fine but I don't need each row to have its own total, I want to display totals of all rows. please help me to finish the remaining one. thank you

Comment: Then give a properly detailed explanation. Calculations done by row or column?

Comment: I need all rows to affect the column of total. This means the calculation of first row, second row and n row will increase value of entire total column. For example after filling all text boxes, first row total is 100 second row total is 100 n row total is 100. If that totals can affect only first row no problem but I think the easy way is to display them in entire column. Thank you charlietfl

Comment: Or if it's possible you can add another column which will calculate total of totals, or add last row which will calculate total of totals. One of them is enough. Thank you

Comment: So loop over each row and use my code to get the total for each row and you add that to a grand total each iteration. When loop is done update what you need to

Comment: Hi all, everything is fine now. Thank you so much